# How to take an int, split it to digits, do some arithmetics and then append it to new int

Tags: python, function

### Task:

Given an integer as input, Add code to take the individual digits and increase by 1.

For example, if the digit is 5, then it becomes 6. Please note that if the digit is 9 it becomes 0.

### More examples

input: 2342         output: 3453

input: 9999         output: 0

input: 835193       output: 946204

I wrote this function but I know for sure this isn't way to write this code and I'm looking for some tips to write it in a more concise, efficient way. Please advise.

```
def new_num (num):
    newnum = []
    for i in range (0,len(str(num))):
        upper = num%10
        print(upper)
        num = int(num/10)
        print(num)
        if upper == 9:
            upper = 0
            newnum.append(upper)
        else:
            upper+=1
            newnum.append(upper)
    strings = [str(newnum) for newnum in newnum]
    a_string = "".join(strings)
    an_integer = str(a_string)
    new_int = int(an_integer[::-1])
    return(new_int)
```

Comment: If your code doesn't work, you should provide specific input and expected vs wrong output, or the complete error traceback if you get an error. If it works, then your question is off-topic for SO, and would probably be a much better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:-

```
n = '2349'
nn = ''
for i in n:
    nn += '0' if i == '9' else str(int(i) + 1)
print(nn)
```

Comment: working great!
if the input is 99 then the output is 00, how I can make it only 0?

Comment: The code that I've shown prints a string. Perhaps it should be print(int(nn))

Comment: Yep. Convert it to an integer. Or else the + just concantanets the string

Answer (score 0):

one of many possible improvements... replace the if/else with:

```
upper = (upper+1)%10
newnum.append(upper)
```

Comment: for the input 331 the return is 4

Comment: That's what it's suppose to do.  But it's suppose to be in the loop, so you must have replaced the code incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
x= input('no = ')
x= '' + x 
ans=[]
for i in x : 
    if int(i) == 9 :
        ans.append(str(0))
    else: 
        ans.append(str(int(i)+1))
ans=''.join(ans)
if int(ans) == 0:
    ans = 0
print(ans.strip('0'))
```

This is the most basic code I can write, it can also be shortened to few lines

Comment: working well, but can't use 9 for a input

Answer (score 0):

```
testInputs = [2342, 9999, 835193, 9]

def new_num (num):
    return int("".join([str((int(d) + 1) % 10) for d in str(num)]))

result =  [new_num(test) for test in testInputs]

print(result)
# [3453, 0, 946204, 0]
```

1. convert the num to string
2. convert the digit by using (int(d) + 1) % 10
3. join back the digits
4. parse the string as int

Answer (score 0):

```
def newnum(x):
    lis = list(str(x))
    new_list = [int(i)+1 if int(i)<9 else 0 for i in lis]
    new_list = map(str,new_list) 
    return int(''.join(new_list))
```

1. Take the number and convert to list of strings
2. Iterate through the list. Convert each element to int and add 1. The condition of digit 9 is included to produce 0 instead of 10
3. Map it back to strings and use join.
4. Return the output as int.

Comment: thanks a lot!
if I want to return the number as int, how can I do it?

Comment: use return int(''.join(new_list)) to return the result as int. It would also solve your question on how to get 0 when you get '00' for 99. I edited the function above to output as int